# learn to built a server for in-app purchase

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, webserver, in-app-purchase

I'm a freshman about the server programming,and now I want to built a server for my ipad app.
This server is used for Server Model of in-app purchase. After the user has paid for the plug-in, he can download the files from my server.

Please provide a solution for How to create the server for Server Model of In- App Purchases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this MStoreKit : https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit

In this you will find out a folder "Server Code". All the information for making a server for IAP (In-App Purchase) is provided in that.

Do let me know, if you need something else.

Comment: thank you very much, Rajan!!! I will learn it carefully. If any question I'll ask for your help.

Comment: If you find my answer as correct or relevant, Please mark it correct. Thanks.